# Null value when reading from a file in Java

Tags: java

So, I am trying to read a file in java. The file contains only one line, and is a batch of settings which are delimited by an asterisk.

The plan is to parse them into an array using .split method, and assign each array index to the right variable.

Unfortunately, though my file is clearly existing, it is returning an null value for the output, which is incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
try {
        try {
            /* Create and display the form */
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (    InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Loaded okay.");
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    String s = System.getenv("APPDATA");
    File f = new File(s + "\\TinyboardMod\\settings.txt");
    if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         // process the line.
            String settingsString = br.readLine();
            Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, settingsString);
            //settings = settingsString.split("\\[");
        }
        br.close();


    }
```

So, the console is showing null in the logger, but, it wouldn't make it that far if the file didn't exist, so the problem lies somewhere in those few lines, I just don't see it

Answer (score 8):

This

```
String settingsString = br.readLine();
```

should be

```
String settingsString = line; // or just use line directly
```

Otherwise, you're reading one line in the `while` loop condition and another in that statement.

Comment: Oh wow. Well, that fixed it. Figured it was something I overlooked.